# Query php não mostra resultado esperado

Tags: php, query

Tenho aqui um problema com uma query pois peço para me mostrar todos os campos que uma determinada condição que numa coluna esteja escrito 'Lisboa', mas o resultado é: Lisboa e porto.

Query:

```
Select * From tb_trabalhador WHERE  (AlvaraNumero = 0 or AlvaraNumero is NULL)  or 
(AlvaraValidade='' or AlvaraValidade is Null or AlvaraValidade='0000-00-00') or (AlvaraAnexo='' or AlvaraAnexo is Null)
 or AcidenteNumero = 0 or (AcidenteValidade='' or AcidenteValidade is Null or AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00')
 or (AcidenteAnexo='' or AcidenteAnexo is Null) or SeguroNumero = 0 or (SeguroValidade='' or SeguroValidade is Null or SeguroValidade='0000-00-00' )
 or (SeguroAnexo='' or SeguroAnexo is Null) or InstaladorNumero = 0 or (InstaladorValidade='' or InstaladorValidade is Null or InstaladorValidade='0000-00-00')
 or (InstaladorAnexo='' or InstaladorAnexo is Null)  AND tb_trabalhador.distrito = 'Lisboa'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só acrescentar um ( depois do where e fechar ) antes do and, para que possas aplicar o and a todos os casos possíveis anteriores.

```
Select * From tb_trabalhador WHERE  ((AlvaraNumero = 0 or AlvaraNumero is NULL)  or 
(AlvaraValidade='' or AlvaraValidade is Null or AlvaraValidade='0000-00-00') or (AlvaraAnexo='' or AlvaraAnexo is Null)
 or AcidenteNumero = 0 or (AcidenteValidade='' or AcidenteValidade is Null or AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00')
 or (AcidenteAnexo='' or AcidenteAnexo is Null) or SeguroNumero = 0 or (SeguroValidade='' or SeguroValidade is Null or SeguroValidade='0000-00-00' )
 or (SeguroAnexo='' or SeguroAnexo is Null) or InstaladorNumero = 0 or (InstaladorValidade='' or InstaladorValidade is Null or InstaladorValidade='0000-00-00')
 or (InstaladorAnexo='' or InstaladorAnexo is Null))  AND tb_trabalhador.distrito = 'Lisboa'
```

Comment: Temos de ter bastante cuidado com esse tipo de coisas porque `A and b or c` é diferente `(a and b) or c` e diferente de `a and (b or c)`. Muito cuidado com as propriedades lógicas.